# Jest set TZ env variable PER test

Tags: javascript, jestjs, ts-jest

I am running into an issue where I want to run *some* of my tests under different time zones.

After following a few links i found that you can set the `TZ` env var before calling `jest` in your package.json or command line like so:

```json
{
  ...
  "test": "TZ=America/Sao_Paulo jest"
  ...
}
```

But this doesn't scale properly say if i want to test both `America/Sao_Paulo` & `Asia/Shanghai`...I'd have to do something like this...

```json
{
  ...
  "test": "TZ=America/Sao_Paulo jest & TZ=Asia/Shanghai jest"
  ...
}
```

I've also tried the approach with setting the timezone by manipulating `process.env.TZ` in `beforeEach` of each test BUT...it never actually picks up on the env when it goes runs my suites.

Comment: "_setting the timezone by manipulating process.env.TZ in beforeEach of each test BUT...it never actually picks up on the env_": This seems unintuitive, I agree, but why use environment variables? Any reason why you're not expressing the test-related time zone information in your source code?

Comment: @jsejcksn I just couldn't get anything like that to work I'm afraid. 
my test cases are essentially testing how the native `new Date` constructor doesn't ignore browser timezone when handling `UTC` and the only way i could consistently mock the timezone of the test environment was to set `TZ` for jest.

Comment: [^](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75059068/jest-set-tz-env-variable-per-test?noredirect=1#comment132471788_75059068) So far, it sounds like an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). Can you show the actual test implementation in a [mre]?

Answer (score 0):

OK I went around the houses a bit but ended up creating a custom bash script called `handleTests.sh` and also renaming my test file to `toUTCDate_test.ts` instead of `toUTCDate.test.ts` to avoid jest picking it up and running it.

My package.json now looks like:

```json
{
  ...
  "test": "./handleTests.sh"
  ...
}
```

> Make sure you run `chmod +x ./handleTests.sh`

#### handleTests.sh

```bash
# run jest like normal...
jest

# run toUTCDate tests, note _test in the file name...
# this is to dodge jest's auto-run and run only on our own terms.
for TZ in America/Los_Angeles America/Sao_Paulo Asia/Shanghai
  do
    TZ=$TZ jest --testRegex toUTCDate_test
  done
```